# While inserting data via LINQ getting an exception: IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I've got a little problem here. Been debugging for like an hour, ajax passes data but... I can't put it into database with linq, because of an error

Even tho I do have auto increment, it says like it is off or something. 
Here is the code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static int Save(int filmID, int rate)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext du = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        du.ratings.InsertOnSubmit(new ratings
        {
            fk_film_id = filmID,
            rating_total = rate,
            rating_votes = 0
        });
        du.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ratings] 
(
    [fk_rating]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [fk_film_id]   INT NOT NULL,
    [rating_total] INT NOT NULL,
    [rating_votes] INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fk_rating] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ratings_films] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([fk_film_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[films] ([film_id])
);
```

Error message here:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in  System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ratings' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What am I doing wrong?

@added model, but I'm not really using this mode here

```
private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

private int _fk_rating;
private int _fk_film_id;
private int _rating_total;
private int _rating_votes;

private EntityRef<films> _film;

public ratings()
{
    this._film = default(EntityRef<films>);
    OnCreated();
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_fk_rating", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
public int fk_rating
{
    get { return this._fk_rating; }
    set 
    {
        if ((this._fk_rating != value))
        {
            this.Onfk_ratingChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._fk_rating = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("fk_rating");
            this.Onfk_ratingChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the model mapped?

Comment: You probably need to use the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute.

Comment: @juharr Tried, the thing is that is that FkRating is not used in this case here. So it doesn't work. @_ @

Comment: You're showing us the wrong model.  We need to see the EF or Linq-toSQL model, not the model you use in your UI or where ever.

Comment: Your primary key is called FkRating? I assume your model is configured with Fluent syntax since there is no key information on the model definition itself... your configuration is probably relevant to the question.

Comment: @juharr You are right, edited post with the right model... At least I hope that I did ;o

Comment: I reckon you've changed the Primary Key to be IDENTITY INSERT since adding the table to your .dbml file.  To check this: open your .dbml file, delete the table, then re-drag'n'drop it into the .dbml file and recompile.

Comment: @MikeGledhill You was right. It happens that I changed it and at some point forgot to re add the tables in .dbml. Would give you thumbs up, but can't @_ @

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to explicitly insert a value into a column that is defined with an IDENTITY property fk_rating.  This property automatically assigns a new numerical ID to each record that is inserted.

You can either

A) Remove the identity property from the column and continue to explicitly specify the value for it in your insert.

B) remove the Rating value from your insert statement and allow the identity property to assign the ID to the record.

C) Set the `Identity_Insert` property in the database table to ON (I would not recommend this)

Comment: This doesn't really help since the OP is not creating the SQL, but instead a Linq-provider is.

Comment: Since Harugawa included the Create Table statement in the original post, I am assuming they have access to make DDL changes to the DB.  If they cannot change the SQL statement being passed then option A or C should resolve the issue.  I do not know what type of data the rating value is but I would assume based on the name of the field that an Identity on this column would not make much sense as it is not meant to be an ID field.